# Weird exception only in 1 user

Tags: android, admob

I've an android app curently in production installed in over 30k devices and used by 3500 people per day. 1 single user is getting this exception repeatedly

WeakHashMap.java line 806

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF flg=0x50200010 (has extras) } in com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.bw@98afaa4
       at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_52226(LoadedApk.java:1329)
       at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.$m$0(-.java:4)
       at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.run(-.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)


Caused by java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
       at java.util.WeakHashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(WeakHashMap.java:806)
       at java.util.WeakHashMap$EntryIterator.next(WeakHashMap.java:845)
       at java.util.WeakHashMap$EntryIterator.next(WeakHashMap.java:844)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.bv.a(bv.java:9)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.bw.onReceive(bw.java:2)
       at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$-android_app_LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args_52226(LoadedApk.java:1319)
       at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.$m$0(-.java:4)
       at android.app.-$Lambda$FilBqgnXJrN9Mgyks1XHeAxzSTk.run(-.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

this is nothing related to my code for sure as it specifies the google.ads package

100% of the crashes come from:

```
Device
Brand: samsung
Model: SM-G570M
Orientation: Portrait
RAM free: 308.34 MB
Disk free: 12.12 GB
Operating System
Version: 8.0.0
Orientation: Portrait
Rooted: No
```

90% of the time the device app is in background

It happens in some googles api code so i cant catch it... does anyone have any idea of the cause? how can i solve

Comment: please add some more information like your admob code,sdk,etc

Comment: Make sure this user has all the latest google play services updates installed.

Or better yet, check the versions on one of the devices that is working correctly and compare the two.

Comment: Are you sure this is the complete stacktrace? It looks like there's a different issue leading to this one.

Comment: @Abbas, this is happening IN PRODUCTION, i have no way to check users app versions or either force them to use specific version

Comment: @tynn, you were right there was some stacktrace i forgot to paste, now is updated

Comment: I'm seeing the same crash in my app. Created a topic at Google Ads SDK forum https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/ZRbDWmJ5Zjw

Comment: Can you provide your onResume onPause codes specific to admobs and also the initialize location of the same.

Comment: As far as i can understand the situation correct, your application is related to Geo-location using google maps API and you have also implemented the google ad service. If you have passed location in adrequest you may cancel it if you don't need it.

Comment: @VanshajDaga, how can you think that the situation is correct, there is some concurrent modification in inner google apis. I start to think this situation is related to google's during deployment time

Comment: @RafaelLima I meant to say that if i understood the situation correctly, not saying that the situation is correct. And yes there is a possibility that google apis code in googleplaysevices somewhere go out sync of each other(map & ads). So its a bug and you should report it to google.

Answer (score 0):

The support reported that they have fixed this crash https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/ZRbDWmJ5Zjw/H9QaxjtGBAAJ

At least I don't see it anymore in Crashlytics.

Comment: "A fix for this issue has been fixed and rolled out to all the current versions. Can you please confirm the frequency of crashes as of today after updating the SDK to the latest version?" this is a shit employee showing how to answer a question. what is the latest version? after updating WHICH SDK?

Comment: there is no update on play-services-ads since MARCH, and play-services-location since october last year... so i would like very much to know which version are you using because what she said is bullshit

Comment: If they say "rolled out" I think they mean it's done remotely. In my case crashes are gone without an app update

Comment: And i use the following versions of sdk:
play-services-location:16.0.0, play-services-ads:17.1.3

Answer (score -1):

I had same in com.google.android.gms error. Please try to differentiate your library.    May be your problem resolve.

```
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.1-android'
     androidTestImplementation("com.google.truth:truth:0.42") 
    {
        exclude group: "com.google.guava", module: "guava"
        }
```